# Return same instance of an object each time

Tags: java, object, static

This is the situation, I have a param value and based on that I need to return a class instance. I want that on each invocation I return the same object.

obj1 and obj2 implement the same interface.

```
class Engine {
    public commonInterface getObj(int param) {
        switch(param) {
            case 1 : return obj1;
            case 2 : return obj2;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this? I understand it's within a JVM.

Comment: Are you looking to return the same instance?  Or is this like a Factory where it creates a new instance every time?

Comment: same instance should be returned.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight People are free to their views, if they feel a singleton pattern is inappropriate then downvoting is there to express this (I happen to think singletons are appropriate but thats hardly the point). Informing people of how they should vote is inappropriate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Here is one way to do it, but it isn't optimal:

This isn't the best way, mainly because the creation of the objects isn't restricted, for it to be optimal the `MyObject` constructor needs to be `private` and the instances need to be on itself.

Initializing the references in the `static {}` block is a better practice than `inline` because you can handle `Exceptions` and other logic before you initialize the references, this is a *best practice*.

But this is what you see in a lot of *quick and dirty* code that is mostly incorrect because the reasons below in the *better* solution.

```
class Engine {

private static final MyObject OBJ1;
private static final MyObject OBJ2;

static
{
    OBJ1 = new MyObject();
    OBJ2 = new MyObject();
}

public MyObject getObj(final int param)
{
    switch (param)
    {
        case 1:
            return Engine.OBJ1;
        case 2:
            return Engine.OBJ2;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%d is not a valid object id", param));
    }
}
```

#### Here is a better way:

This is better because it hides the implementation. Having a inner class allows you to make the class `public` but make the constructor `private` and control access to the creation of the `MyObject` instances.

```
public class Engine 
{
    private static final MyObject OBJ1;
    private static final MyObject OBJ2;

    static
    {
        OBJ1 = new MyObject1();
        OBJ2 = new MyObject2();
    }

    public MyObject getObj(final int param)
    {
        switch (param)
        {
            case 1:
                return Engine.OBJ1;
            case 2:
                return Engine.OBJ2;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%d is not a valid object id", param));
        }
    }

    public static class MyObject1 implements MyObject { private MyObject1() {} } 
    public static class MyObject2 implements MyObject { private MyObject2() {} } 

}
```

#### Best long term solution, using the most modern idiom at this time:

This solutions is more verbose, but also the most *correct* in enforcing the semantics of a `Singleton`. This method **guarrantees** that the `Singleton` contract in the current JVM. It also scales to multiple classloaders and multiple JVMs but allowing you to just change the `MBeanServer` to a different implemenation, and looks up the references remotely without changing any other code. *DI/IoC is intentionally ignored here for simplicity*.

```
import javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException;
import javax.management.JMX;
import javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class Engine
{
    private static final MyObject OBJ1;
    private static final MyObject OBJ2;

    static
    {
        try
        {
            final MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
            final ObjectName on1 = new ObjectName("com.example:type=MyObject1");
            final ObjectName on2 = new ObjectName("com.example:type=MyObject2");
            OBJ1 = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbs, on1, MyObject.class);
            OBJ2 = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbs, on2, MyObject.class);
        }
        catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
    }

    public MyObject getObj(final int param)
    {
        switch (param)
        {
            case 1:
                return Engine.OBJ1;
            case 2:
                return Engine.OBJ2;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%d is not a valid object id", param));
        }
    }

    public static class MyObject1 implements MyObjectMBean
    {
        static
        {
            try
            {
                final MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
                final ObjectName on1 = new ObjectName("com.example:type=MyObject1");
                mbs.registerMBean(new MyObject1(), on1);
            }
            catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
            catch (NotCompliantMBeanException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
            catch (InstanceAlreadyExistsException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
            catch (MBeanRegistrationException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }

        private MyObject1() { /* your interface implementations go here */ }
    }

    public static class MyObject2 implements MyObjectMBean
    {
        static
        {
            try
            {
                final MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
                final ObjectName on1 = new ObjectName("com.example:type=MyObject2");
                mbs.registerMBean(new MyObject2(), on1);
            }
            catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
            catch (NotCompliantMBeanException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
            catch (InstanceAlreadyExistsException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
            catch (MBeanRegistrationException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }

        private MyObject2() { /* your interface implementations go here */ }
    }

    private static interface MyObjectMBean extends MyObject { /* mbean specific methods go here */ }
    private static interface MyObject { /* your interface methods go here */ }
}
```

The added benefit of using the JMX approach is you can manage these instances with `JConsole` very easily, while the application is running, you get that for *free*!

*NOTE: I used a single file with the `interfaces` as inner classes for expediency, they could be in their own files without a problem.*

Comment: just to omit :static
    {
       OBJ2 = new Object();
       OBJ2 = new Object();
     }

Comment: Thanks..this looks good..now what if these Obj1 and Obj2 need parameters..which are set within the Engine class's constructor?

Comment: @user1071840 then use the approach I propose of using a `static final Map` instead of marking the fields as `static final`.

Comment: the inner class approach wont work for me as the OBJ1 and OBJ2 are of different types (they implement the same interface).

Comment: The inner class approach will work, you just make both of them inner classes. See my edit on the **better** approach. The `map` suggestion is horrible, it isn't thread safe, it isn't immutable, it isn't a good solution to follow.

Comment: Can you edit to include the criteria that you use to tell whether an implementation of Singleton is good or not?

Comment: Again, I can't initialize the object in the static construct as it requires 2 parameters which are not available until Engine is constructed.

Answer (score 3):

Make the two instances `static`, and instantiate them once, and return only them. This is similar to a [*Singleton*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.

```
class Engine {
    private static commonInterface obj1 = ...
    private static commonInterface obj2 = ...
    public commonInterface getObj(int param) {
        switch(param) {
            case 1 : return obj1;
            case 2 : return obj2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +2 for being first and to being simple.  -1 for being silly in the comments.  Total = +1.  |=^)

Comment: @MohammadS. Someone (actually, I think at least two members) went through all the answers and downvoted them without reading (there's a deleted answer that got downvotes within seconds of being posted). I am writing a question on meta to discuss this situation.

Comment: Good luck with that.  I asked a question just like that on the meta, and it got down-voted by 20 or so people in minutes.  I guess you can say this site is "stackoverflowed" with idiots.

Comment: @MohammadS. Well, I'll try anyway: who cares about rep, especially on the meta site, right?

Comment: I agree with you, so I'll support you.  Just word it carefully (and not with hasty rage like I did).

Comment: This is ideally what I want to do, except the obj1 and obj2 need a parameter for construction which comes from class Engine's constructor.

Comment: @user1071840 You can set `obj1` and `obj2` in the constructor of your engine, too. You should check if these objects already exist before setting them.

Answer (score 1):

One way can be using `enum`s instead:

```
public enum CommonInterfaceImpl implements CommonInterface {
    Obj1,
    Obj2;

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("this is foo implementation");
    }
}
```

And in your method return the desired `enum`:

```
class Engine {
    public commonInterface getObj(int param) {
        switch(param) {
            case 1 : return CommonInterfaceImpl.Obj1;
            case 2 : return CommonInterfaceImpl.Obj2;
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach can be using a `static final Map<Integer, CommonInterface>` where you set all your objects and just retrieve it in the method as you want/need. This approach is even more flexible than having `enum`s of predefined `static` variables:

```
class Engine {
    static final Map<Integer, CommonInterface> mapHolder = new HashMap<Integer, CommonInterface>();

    static {
        //bare example...
        //note that all this code can be replaced to load the classes dynamically
        CommonInterface obj1 = ...;
        CommonInterface obj2 = ...;
        mapHolder.put(1, obj1);
        mapHolder.put(2, obj2);
    }

    //note that the map can be filled in other methods of the Engine class...
    private void loadParameters() {
        CommonInterface obj3 = ...;
        CommonInterface obj4 = ...;
        mapHolder.put(3, obj3);
        mapHolder.put(4, obj4);
    }

    public commonInterface getObj(int param) {
        return mapHolder.get(param);
    }
}
```